# How to remove userprofile from User Profile Service Application in Powershel?

Tags: user-profile-service

I am using sp 2010. How can I remove a userprofile from the User Profile Service Application in Powershel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get a reference to the UserProfileManager object, get the user profile object, and then call RemoveUserProfile() on it. Here is an example script:

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Delete-all-User-Profiles-fa4e1428

Note that this particular script deletes ALL user profiles; you'll need to modify it to locate a specific user profile (using a login name, for example) before deleting just that one profile.